# Does relative bias exist?

Tags: estimation, terminology, bias, definition

The bias of an estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is defined as $Bias = E[\hat{\theta}]-\theta$. I want to standardize this value to compare the bias of different parameters. Can I report the following quantity instead?

$$\dfrac{E[\hat{\theta}]-\theta}{\theta}.$$

Does this quantity has another name than relative bias?

Comment: If $\theta = 0$, what will you do?

Comment: You can always used a normalized bias

$(\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}] - \theta) / \sqrt{\mathbb{V}(\hat{\theta})}$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is called relative bias:

https://sisu.ut.ee/lcms_method_validation/51-Bias-and-its-constituents

Obviously, you need $\theta \neq 0$, and to be careful with the sign of $\theta$.